# Prime factor in model

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework, asp.net-web-api2

I have an Entity Framework model, it has a number in it. I want to break it to prime factors. I have a list of valid prime numbers in an array.

My question in design related. I don't want to store the prime factor in the database, in the database I store the number only. But when I load the application, I need to print out the prime factor of all the numbers stored.

Now I don't want to make the prime breakedown in the view, I want to do it in the controller. So I need I guess I need to have the prime factor list in the model. But I don't want to allow having a number set without the prime factors:

```
PrimeFactor pf = new PrimeFactor() {number=12}
Console.WriteLine (pf.Primefactor) //0
```

So I created the primefactor property in the modell, with a getter, so the factorization happens in the model, so I also stored the valid prime number list in the model, but this looks horrible, with 2 NotMappedfields.

```
public class PrimeFactor
{
    [NotMapped]
    public static readonly int[] Primes = { 2,3,5,7,13 };

    [Key] 
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public decimal Number { get; set; }

    [NotMapped]
    public List<int> Pimefactor { get { return factor(Number); } }

    private List<int> factor(decimal number) {
        List<int> list = new List<int>();

        // breakdown here using Primes. 
        return list;
    }

}
```

Is there a better way to do this?
thanks

Comment: 'But I don't want to allow having a number set without the prime factors' - can you please explain this part a bit more?

Comment: For example I don't want to allow this:
PrimeFactor pf = new PrimeFactor() {number=12}
Console.WriteLine (pf.Primefactor) //0

Comment: Yes, but the question is where does that kind of setting come from? Is it something users submit to your controller and you want to do some validation that number can be broken down to prime factors before saving to db? or something else?

Comment: user can type a number into a text box, that needs to be broken down to prime factors. Validation doesn't matter.